# SQL query to merge 2 tables with additional conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 identical tables: user_id, name, age, date_added.
USER_ID column may contain multiple duplicate IDs.

Need to merge those 2 tables into 1 with the following condition. 
If there are multiple records with identical 'name' for the same user then need to keep only the LATEST (by date_added) record. 
This script will be used with MSSQL 2005, but would also appreciate if somebody comes up with version that does not use ROW_NUMBER(). Need this script to reload a broken table once, performance is not critical.

example:

table1:

```
1,'john',21,01/01/2010

1,'john',15,01/01/2005

1,'john',71,01/01/2001
```

table2:

```
1,'john',81,01/01/2007

1,'john',15,01/01/2005

1,'john',11,01/01/2008
```

result:

```
1,'john',21,01/01/2010
```

UPDATE:
I think that I've found my own solution. It is based on an answer for my previous question given by Larry Lustig and Joe Stefanelli.

with tmp2 as
(
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
)

SELECT * FROM tmp2 c1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp2 c2 
       WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id AND 
             c2.name = c1.name AND 
             c2.date_added >= c1.date_added) <= 1

Could you please help me to convert this query to the one without 'WITH' clause?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: I am still working on it. Do not have good working solution yet. Will definitely post it here if I will come up with one before somebody else will post their own here.

Comment: begin with writing a select statement that returns the unique user ids and maximum dates - this is straightforward group by - then wrap that into an insert statement.

Comment: Why the requirement to avoid `row_number` if you are only running it once and it will be on a 2005 server?

Comment: @MArtin: There is no firm requirement not to use row_number, but I like to learn ways how to construct some complex queries by using a combination of basic SELECT statements.

Comment: Ah OK. You can also use `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP` to do this then as well as Andomar's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `not exists`, like:

```
; with all_users as 
        (
        select  *
        from    table1 u1
        union all
        select  *
        from    table2 u2
        )
select  *
from    all_users u1
where   not exists  
        (
        select  *
        from    all_users u2
        where   u1.name = u2.name
                and u1.record_time < u2.record_time
        )
```

If the database doesn't support CTE's, expand `all_users` in the two places it is used.

P.S. If there are only three columns, and no more, you could use an even simpler solution:

```
select  name
,       MAX(record_time)
from    (
        select  *
        from    table1 u1
        union all
        select  *
        from    table2 u2
        ) sub
group by
        name
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the 1st solution. I think that 'where' should have at lest u1.user_id=u2.user_id and something else. The 2nd solution is not good, because it does not select AGE. My real table has more columns than I listed in description.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of @Andomar's answer:

```
; with all_users as 
    (
    select  *
    from    table1 u1
    union all
    select  *
    from    table2 u2
    )
, ranker as (
     select  *, 
     rank() over (partition by userid order by recordtime) as [r]
)
select * from ranker where [r] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in the interests of giving a different approach...

```
WITH distinctlist
     As (SELECT user_id,
                name
         FROM   table1
         UNION
         SELECT user_id,
                name
         FROM   table2)
SELECT C.*
FROM   distinctlist d
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 *
                            FROM   table1
                            WHERE  user_id = d.user_id
                                   AND name = d.name
                            ORDER  BY date_added DESC
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT TOP 1 *
                            FROM   table1
                            WHERE  user_id = d.user_id
                                   AND name = d.name
                            ORDER  BY date_added DESC) T
                    ORDER  BY date_added DESC) C
```